# single word for improving little by little

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to remember a word which means "improve little by little", I'm not sure if it's just dialect where I'm from or if it's a proper word. Hopefully you guys can throw a few words at me.

> If you practice guitar everyday you will ________, and eventually be a master.

Comment: Single word requests must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: My apologies, I have added an example.

Comment: *[get better](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/get-better)* is pretty basic

Comment: *Refine*, but it's not quite a drop-in for your example.

Comment: "Get better *in fits and starts*" is one old idiom.

Comment: *progress incrementally*

Answer (score 3):

I need to tweak your example a little, and phrase it as:

> If you practice guitar everyday, your skills will **grow incrementally**, and you will eventually become a master.

The key missing word here is *incrementally*, using this definition [from M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incremental):

> of, relating to, being, or occurring in especially small increments <incremental additions> <incremental change>

Answer (score 2):

**Progress**?

> to grow or develop, as in complexity, scope, or severity; advance:
> <sub>[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/progress)</sub>

---

> If you practice guitar everyday you will progress, and eventually be a master.

In your example, however, I would use **improve**.

> If you practice guitar everyday you will improve, and eventually be a master.

Comment: Suggest you use definition of *progress* as a verb.

Answer (score 1):

I like [***better***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/better) (verb):

Make (something) better; improve.

> ‘Swimming regularly betters the functioning of the heart and lungs.’ (Oxford Living Dictionaries)

To become better:

> Conditions bettered with time. [(TFT)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Better)

Answer (score 0):

If you practice the guitar every day, you will **gradually increase** your dexterity and eventually become a master.

> - **gradual** - "developing slowly or by small increments"  - [**TDF**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gradually)